# GCC warning: This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories. What does it means?

Tags: lubuntu, compiling, gcc, zlib

After running `configure` of GCC 9.2.0, I get this warning:

> *** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
>
> gnattools gotools target-libada target-libhsail-rt target-libphobos target-zlib target-libgo target-libffi
>   target-liboffloadmic
>
> (Any other directories should still work fine.)

I do not care abaout D, ADA and GO. What perplex me are:

- target-zlib
- target-libffi

These warning mean that GCC will be compiled without zip and libffi support?

I'm on Lubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: Hopefully you mean `../gcc-9.2.0/configure --[options] --` .. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DnxKV_MOGJDwZ0mDIARrooYf9kUDPQlv/view?usp=sharing ... Please note that languages must be specified like `--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran` .

Comment: @KnudLarsen I renamed the dir, and supported languages are automatically enabled, as `configure` assure me in output. Anywya, what about the "This configuration" message?

Comment: I have built the most gcc versions 3.2.3 .... 9.2.0 several times https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j7qE9YKTT313B5VBg3kevzCNiykGkonO?usp=sharing over the last many years, and don't remember seeing  a "gcc message" like yours. Can probably be avoided with a proven configure line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [gcc-help mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2020-02/msg00092.html):

> On Wed, 19 Feb 2020 at 02:33, Xi Ruoyao wrote:
>
> Target zlib is only necessary for libphobos (which is then used by D
>   runtime) and target libffi is only necessary for Go runtime.  D and Go
>   are not enabled by default.

Since, as I said, I'm not interested in such languages, this is not a problem :)